# How to make the heatmap legend in ggplot2 3.0.0 with the same height as my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, colorbar

This is the same question as mentioned in [How can I make the legend in ggplot2 the same height as my plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214914/how-can-i-make-the-legend-in-ggplot2-the-same-height-as-my-plot/29783981#29783981?newreg=13c13a885bcf479aa98130427b74bc83). But when I update the ggplot2 to 3.0.0 version, Sandy Muspratt's answer doesn't work. It is because that

```
leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[3]]$y = pos
```

doesn't work any more for ggplot2 3.0.0 changes the `leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[3]]` item. Does anyone know what to do with 3.0 version?

Here is the code of Sandy Muspratt's answer

```
# Load the needed libraries
library(ggplot2) #Version should be 3.0.0
library(gtable)  # 
library(grid)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)

# Generate a collection of sample data
variables = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")
data = matrix(runif(9, -1, 1), 3, 3)
diag(data) = 1
colnames(data) = variables
rownames(data) = variables

# Generate the plot
corrs = data
plot  = ggplot(melt(corrs), aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  # theme(legend.position = "right", legend.key.height = unit(1, "inch")) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "", title = "Correlation Coefficients") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(limits = c(-1, 1), breaks = c(-1, -.5, 0, .5, 1), expand = c(0,0), 
                       low = muted("red"), mid = "black", high = muted("blue")) +  # Modified line
  geom_text(parse = TRUE, aes(label = sprintf("%.2f", value)), size = 3, color = "white") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +  # New line
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))    # New line
plot

# Get the ggplot grob
gt = ggplotGrob(plot)

# Get the legend
leg = gtable_filter(gt, "guide-box")

# Raster height
leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]$height = unit(1, "npc")

# Positions for labels and tick marks - five breaks, therefore, five positions
pos = unit.c(unit(0.01,"npc"), unit(.25, "npc"), unit(.5, "npc"), unit(.75, "npc"), unit(.99, "npc"))

# Positions the labels 
leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[3]]$y = pos

# Positions the tick marks
leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[5]]$y0 = pos
leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[5]]$y1 = pos

# Legend key height ?
leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]$heights = unit.c(rep(unit(0, "mm"), 3),
                                         unit(1, "npc"),
                                         unit(0, "mm"))
# Legend height
leg[[1]][[1]]$heights[[3]] = sum(rep(unit(0, "mm"), 3),
                                 unit(1, "npc"),
                                 unit(0, "mm"))

# grid.draw(leg)  # Check on heights and y values

# gtable_show_layout(gt) # Manually locate position of legend in layout
gt.new = gtable_add_grob(gt, leg, t = 7, l = 9)

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt.new)
```

And here is the result. You could see that there's something wrong with the legend text position.
[image]

Comment: Please modify your question according to [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The offending line should be: `leg[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[3]]$children[[1]]$y = pos`   I've edited the post.