# ggplot colorbar to panel height with patched graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Let's assume I have a set of charts using `ggplot` that I patch together using `patchwork`. All charts are having the same legend and I want to have one legend on the right-hand side that is as high as my patched plots. This works using a custom function for a single chart, but once it is patched together, it no longer works. Are there any work arounds to achieve the same behavior for patched charts?

For simplicity, I use the same chart four times.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)
t <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.001)
p <- length(t) - 1
n <- 5
I <- matrix(rnorm(n * p, 0, 1 / sqrt(p)), n, p)
df <- data.frame(apply(I, 1, cumsum))
df <- data.frame(x = seq_along(df[, 1]), df)
df <- melt(df, id.vars = "x")
df$variable <- as.numeric(df$variable)

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.5))

gg + gg + gg + gg
```

This creates the following chart:

[image: example]

However, ideally I want to have the colorbar as high as the plot. For a single chart this looks as follows:

```
make_fullsize <- function() structure("", class = "fullsizebar")

ggplot_add.fullsizebar <- function(obj, g, name = "fullsizebar") {
  h <- ggplotGrob(g)$heights
  panel <- which(grid::unitType(h) == "null")
  panel_height <- unit(1, "npc") - sum(h[-panel])
  
  g + 
    guides(color = guide_colorbar(barheight = panel_height,
                                  title.position = "right")) +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0.5))
}

gg +
  make_fullsize()
```

[image: desired output]

Collecting the legend in `patchwork` works as intended. However, this does not work in conjunction with `make_fullsize()`.

```
gg + gg + gg + gg +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image: patched charts with common legend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an adaption of the original [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956186/12993861) by  @AllanCameron which also accounts for the case of a `patchwork` with collected (!!) guides:

```r
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)
t <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.001)
p <- length(t) - 1
n <- 5
I <- matrix(rnorm(n * p, 0, 1 / sqrt(p)), n, p)
df <- data.frame(apply(I, 1, cumsum))
df <- data.frame(x = seq_along(df[, 1]), df)
df <- melt(df, id.vars = "x")
df$variable <- as.numeric(df$variable)

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  viridis::scale_color_viridis() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, linewidth = 0.5))

make_fullsize <- function() {
  structure(
    "",
    class = "fullsizebar"
  )
}

ggplot_add.fullsizebar <- function(obj, g, name = "fullsizebar") {
  is_patch <- inherits(g, "patchwork")
  if (is_patch) {
    p <- patchworkGrob(g)
    ix_panel <- grep("^panel\\-area", p$layout$name)
  } else {
    p <- ggplotGrob(g)
    ix_panel <- grep("^panel", p$layout$name)
  }
  h <- p$heights

  panel_t <- p$layout[ix_panel, "t"]
  panel_b <- p$layout[ix_panel, "b"]

  panel_height <- unit(1, "npc") - sum(h[-seq(panel_t, panel_b)])

  layers <- list(
    guides(color = guide_colorbar(
      barheight = panel_height,
      title.position = "right"
    )),
    theme(legend.title = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0.5))
  )
  
  if (is_patch) {
    g & layers
  } else {
    g + layers
  }
}

gg + gg + gg + gg +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") +
  make_fullsize()
```

[image]

```r
(gg / gg) +
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") +
  make_fullsize()
```

[image]

```r
gg +
  make_fullsize()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for adapting the code to collected guides. Running the current code leads in my case to the following error `Error in seq.default(panel_t, panel_b) : 'from' must be of length 1`.  It seems that `grep("^panel\\-area", p$layout$name)` is not properly extracting the panels.  Adjusting this to `grep("^panel", p$layout$name)` and changing the specification of `panel_t <- p$layout[ix_panel, "t"][1]` and `panel_b <- p$layout[ix_panel, "b"][length(p$layout[ix_panel, "b"])]`accordingly seems to do the trick in multiple specifications.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what's different in your case. The layout of patchwork contains multiple panels and a panel-area. That's why I went for `panel\\-area`.

Comment: Very nice @stefan. I had a look at this last night and figured it would probably take a conditional version of the `ggplot_add` function that used `patchworkGrob`, but I thought the parsing and calculation might be more complex than you have made it look. This deserves more upvotes.

Comment: In my case running `panel\\-area` leads to an empty vector. When looking into `p$layout$name`, the panels are recorded as "panel-1" and "panel-2" in the case of two plots., which is why the extraction causes issues.

Comment: Still not able to reproduce your issue. Whether there are four or only two or even only one plot in the patch should not make a difference (as you can see from the two plot example in my answer). My guess is that we are using different versions of `patchwork`. Mine is `1.1.3` and after a look at the commit history the `panel-area` element was added in 1.1.3. See https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/commit/94f04c42f2e8f90456b0f063e3a93336d17485db

Comment: I can confirm that this is a version issue. Thanks for the very neat solution.