# ggplot colorbar align to top when using facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am using facetted plots via `ggplot` that contain a colorbar. I want to scale the colorbar to the size of the facetted plot. Following the ideas of @AllanCameron in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214914/how-can-i-make-the-legend-color-bar-the-same-height-as-my-plot-panel/74956186#74956186) regarding a single plot and tweaking the function to account for both the strip size and the space between plots, I am able to correctly work out the size of the legend. Thereby, the size of the legend is correctly specified irrespective of the `ncol`, `panel.spacing.y`, or `strip.text.x` specification.

However, by default, the legend is centered between the two plots without strips. Adjusting the legend via `legend.position` or `legend.justification` did so far not help to correctly specify it. **How can I properly align the legend with the top of the chart** i.e., the top of the strip (see the plot on the right side for the exptected output)?

[image: example]

I only aligned in the right chart the legend to the top without adjusting the size using an external graphics programme. Thus, while the legend height looks too small in the picture on the left chart, the size is actually fine.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- expand.grid(
  x = c(1, 2, 3),
  y = c(1, 2, 3),
  g = c("one", "two", "three", "four")
)

set.seed(1)
df$v <- runif(nrow(df), min = 0, max = 1)

make_fullsize <- function() structure("", class = "fullsizebar")

ggplot_add.fullsizebar <- function(obj, g, name = "fullsizebar") {
  h <- ggplotGrob(g)$heights
  panel <- which(grid::unitType(h) == "null")
  panel_height <- unit(1, "npc") - sum(h[-c(panel, (panel-1), grep("lines", h))])

  g + 
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barheight = panel_height,
                                 title.position = "right")) +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0.5))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = v)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ g, ncol = 2) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "lines"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, margin = margin(2,0,2,0, "cm")),
        strip.background.x = element_rect(
        colour = "black", linewidth = 1)) +
  make_fullsize()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the original [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956186/12993861) by  @AllanCameron and my [adapted approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547290/12993861) we can easily compute the correct bar height. However, to achieve your desired result requires some additional tweaks via `theme`. Set the `legend.justification` to `bottom` and remove the top and bottom `legend.margin`:

```
library(ggplot2)

make_fullsize <- function() structure("", class = "fullsizebar")

ggplot_add.fullsizebar <- function(obj, g, name = "fullsizebar") {
  p <- ggplotGrob(g)
  
  h <- p$heights
  
  ix_panel <- grep("^panel", p$layout$name)
  ix_strip <- grep("^strip", p$layout$name)
  
  panel_t <- min(p$layout[ix_strip, "t"])
  panel_b <- max(p$layout[ix_panel, "b"])
  
  barheight <- unit(1, "npc") - sum(h[-seq(panel_t, panel_b)])
  
  g +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(
      barheight = barheight,
      title.position = "right"
    )) +
    theme(
      legend.justification = "bottom",
      legend.margin = margin(0, 5.5, 0, 5.5),
      legend.title = element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0.5)
    )
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = v)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ g, ncol = 2) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(
    panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "lines"),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, margin = margin(2, 0, 2, 0, "cm")),
    strip.background.x = element_rect(
      colour = "black", linewidth = 1
    )
  ) +
  make_fullsize()

ggsave("foo.png", width = 5, height = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this elegant approach. As an extension, I tried to scale the colorbar only up to the "four" strip. The idea was to change `min(p$layout[ix_strip, "t"])` simply to `max(p$layout[ix_strip, "t"])` because this would in theory make up the height of the two bottom components. Appartently, this does not work. The resulting colorbar is then exactly the size of the two panels plus 1 strip. Do you know how I can additionally deduct the height of 1 panel, without hard-coding it, e.g., `-unit(x, "mm")`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that easy in this case. After a look the problem I think that this requires some manipulation of the gtable. But as of the moment I wasn't able to come with a working solution. Would suggest to ask a new question.

Comment: This idea of additionally deducting everything except panel height from `unit(1, "npc")` and account for number of panels to get the right size works for equally-sized panels irrespective of `ncol` and `spacing`. Thereby, the size is always as high as the lowest facet. 
Change `panel_t` to `max(p$layout[ix_strip, "t"])`. 
Get # of unique panels: `panel_n <- length(unique(p$layout[grep("^panel", p$layout$name), "t"]))`. 
Set barheight incl. additional deduction:
`barheight <- unit(1, "npc") - sum(h[-seq(panel_t, panel_b)]) -
(unit(1, "npc") - sum(h[-panel_b])) * ((panel_n - 1) / panel_n)`.

Comment: Great. Really nice. Would suggest to create a new question and add your solution as a (self-)answer. Then I can upvote it. :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:
Main feature is to center the original legend with `strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, margin = margin(2,0,-5,0, "cm")), # necessery to center the legend vertically -5`, but then the other text is also moved -> therefore:
extract the legend and put it to the first plot (that is created without legend). We then use grid.arrange with a layout matrix to position legend and plot.
Here is the code.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr) # get_legend()
# create the plot without legend
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = v)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ g, ncol = 2) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "lines"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, margin = margin(2,0,2,0, "cm")),
        strip.background.x = element_rect(
          colour = "black", linewidth = 1)) +
  guides(fill="none")
p1

# create the plot with legend
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = v)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ g, ncol = 2) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(fill = "") +
  theme(panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "lines"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, margin = margin(2,0,-5,0, "cm")), # necessery to center the legend vertically -5
        strip.background.x = element_rect(colour = "black", linewidth = 1),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.justification = "center",
        legend.box.just = "center",
        legend.box.margin = margin(t = 1, b = 30), # play around with t and b
        legend.key.height = unit(12.8, "line") # increases the height of the legend
  )
p2

# extract the legend
legend <- get_legend(p2)

# layout matrix for grid arrange
layout_matrix <- matrix(c(1, 2), nrow = 1, byrow = TRUE)

# Adjust the width and height, play around
widths_vector <- c(10, 1) 
heights_vector <- c(4, 0.001) 

# Arrange the plot and legend with adjusted width and height
grid.arrange(p1, legend, layout_matrix = layout_matrix, heights = heights_vector, widths = widths_vector)
```

[image]